# Запуск python файлов на другом устройсве

Tags: python, компиляция, build, pyinstaller

Мне нужно (хотя бы в теории) узнать, как запустить (или чтобы она сама запускалась) какую-либо python программу на устройстве, в котором отсутствует python.

Имею ввиду то, что после отправки файла от меня к другому человеку, он 100% запустился,  исключая то, что человеку (которому файл был отправлен) пришлось бы самостоятельно что-то докачивать (к примеру, тот же питон).

Answer (score 2):

Можно скомпилировать python на Windows при помощи pyinstaller или же py2exe.
Ещё были pyWin32, cx_freeze для тех же целей.
На *nix pyhton практически всегда есть в дефлотной поставке.

Comment: На unix системах питон есть, но это может быть не та версия (я на питоне 3.7 ,а на маке дефолт питон 2.7 ,так что надо ставить),может не хватать модулей.
Мое мнение для *nix надо собирать отдельно.(MacОSХ  — py2app,pyinstaller , Linux — pyinstaller)
Можно еще nuitka.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный способ - это упаковка скриптов вместе с компактной версией интерпретатора в самораспаковывающийся архив с помощью cx_freeze, pyinstaller и тому подобного.

Comment: Насколько я знаю nuitka компиляет питон в cpp ,а потом в исполняемый.Так что не совсем так.

Comment: @Victor трансляторы типа Nuitka и Cython преобразуют python-код в Cишный, выполняющий те же операции с помощью Python/C API, и на выходе действительно получается настоящий бинарник. Но он не полноценен без среды выполнения, для запуска ему нужна Python VM и стандартная библиотека. Есть так называемый embed-режим, но с ним очень много тонкостей и сложностей.

Comment: На винде если скомпилировать  .py в exe, то ,помимо exe, будет python<версия>.dll и некоторые другие файлы.Я так понимаю python<версия>.dll это компактная  версия интерпретатора.А _<moduleName>.pyd это модули(.pyd тот же  самый .dll ).Но ведь  можно скомпилировать python  в одну экзешку.